# Silk codec support by Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Silk codec support by Windows Phone 8. How do I use that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. My understanding is that silk was developed by Skype and there is no way to utilize the codec outside of the Skype client on Windows Phone8.

However the good news is that silk was incorporate into the Opus codec, which was created from SILK (voice codec) and CELT.

You didn't say what you are trying to accomplish so read more about Opus here http://www.opus-codec.org/

Comment: I was downloaded some SILK codec files and played in Windows Phone 8 device and Emulator, it is working fine but I don't know how write a file in specific codec format.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad can you show those files? Are there headers in each file?